# Sorting and storing array returned by a method as parent and child data for displaying nested/multi level comments in codeigniter 2.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

Hey guys I'm trying to learn codeigniter, but once again I'm STUCK and I seek help (as usual :P )

`What I need to do?`
-> I need to get the data related to a article from the database along with other stuff like the tags for the article and all the `comments`. I'm thinking of keeping single level nested comments for the article.

Well I'm done with the tag part [link to the answer which helped me with the same : [Returning and using multidimensional array of records from database in CodeIgniter 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987951/returning-and-using-multidimensional-array-of-records-from-database-in-codeignite) ] but the `comment part` is driving me nuts.
Well to get started here is my comments table

```
Comments
+---------------+-------------+
| Field         | Type        |
+---------------+-------------+
| commentId     | int(10)     |
| PostId        | int(10)     |
| author        | varchar(30) |
| email         | varchar(30) |
| url           | varchar(50) |
| date          | datetime    |
| comment       | text        |
| parent        | int(10)     | 
+---------------+-------------+
```

I'm using the parent field to keep a track of the parent for a nested child comment. By default the value is 0 which means it  the parent. Child comment will have the commentid of its parent comment

```
    public function getPost($postName = NULL , $year = NULL, $month = NULL ){
        if($postName != NULL && $year != NULL && $month != NULL){
            //single post
            $this->load->model('comment_model');
            $this->db->where('postName',$postName);
            $this->db->where('year(date)',$year);
            $this->db->where('month(date)',$month);
            $q = $this->db->get('mstack_Post'); 
            if($q->num_rows()>0){
                $post = $q->result();
                foreach ($post as &$p) {
                    $p->tags = $this->getAllTags($p->postId);   

                      /* getting the comments */
                    $com = $this->comment_model->getComments($p->postId); 

                    /*echo count($com).' is the total count'; output= 4 */
                    foreach ($com as &$c) {
                                      /* trying to filter the comment. but all I get is 1 comment as the output*/
                        if($c->parent==0){
                            $p->comments->parentComment = $c;
                        }elseif($c->commentId==$c->parent){
                            $p->comments->childComment = $c;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return $post;
            }else{
                return array();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help will surely be appreciated.
If you have any other technique /idea to display multi level comments then do let me know. :)

Comment: One thing: write `if($c->parent == '0')`, I think without quotes you're evaluating it to false, then using always the elseif. Please correct me if I'm wrong on this.

Comment: okay I'll try it out and let you know if it works

Comment: $c->commentId == $c->parent??  maybe it should be $p->postId.  put a simple else and print_r($c) to see which records satisfy neither conditions.

Comment: @kinjal You are right there is something wrong in that part of the code.I added a else part and tried printing the array it printed me all the child comments (which had a value different from 0 in the parent field). The first block of `if ($c->parent==0)` print only one comment no matter what I do.

Comment: @charanraj, just change the elseif part to a simple else... if the parentid is not 0, then it is a child comment, and it will be a comment from this postid because of the way the query is written.  your next problem is that $p->comments->childComment = $c will hold only one comment.  it should be an array for it to hold multiple comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that might be helpfull:

First you need 2 helper recursive function:

```
// Building comments.
function buildComments($list, $parent = 0)
{
    // Creating result array.
    $result = array();

    //looping...
    foreach ($list as $item)
    {
        //iteration starts with 0 as default.
        if ($item->parent == $parent)
        {
            // add to the result
            $result[$item->commentId] = array(
                'author' => $item->author,
                // ... other definitions
                'child' => buildComments($list, $item->commentId) //execute this function for child.
            );
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

function printComments($arg, $depth = 1)
{
    foreach ($arg as $item)
    {
        // Printing comment...
        echo str_repeat('&nbsp; ', $depth) . $item['author'] . "<br />\r\n";
        // extra echoes...

        // if it has a child comment...
        if (count($item['child'] > 0))
        {
            printComments($item['child'], $depth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

A little explaining:

The `buildComments()` function will starts with rows that parents has 0. Then it will execute itself for child. if child as a child, it will add it. In the end, result will be like this:

```
$result = array(
    1 => array(
        'author' => 'John',
        'child' => array(
            8 => array(
                'author' => 'Jane',
                'child' => array(
                    3 => array(
                        'author' => 'Jamie',
                        'child => array()
                    )
                )
            ),
            6 => array(
                'author' => 'Jackie',
                'child => array()
            ),
            9 => array(
                'author' => 'Harry',
                'child => array()
            )

        )
    ),
    4 => array(
        'author' => 'Jack',
        'child' => array()
    ),
    10 => array(
        'author' => 'Clark',
        'child' => array(
            11 => array(
                'author => 'Lois',
                'child' => array()
            )
        )
    ),
    12 => array(
        'author' => 'Luthor',
        'child' => array()
    )
);
```

In the `printComments()` function we are printing results recursive. for each child, function repeats itself. You will get result like this:

```
  John
    Jane
      Jamie
    Jackie
    Harry
  Jack
  Clark
    Lois
  Luthor
```

For more information about recursive functions Look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648968/what-is-a-recursive-function-in-php)

**USAGE**

```
$this->db->where('postName',$postName);
$this->db->where('year(date)',$year);
$this->db->where('month(date)',$month);
$this->db->order_by('parent', 'asc');
$query = $this->db->get('comments');

$comments = buildComments($query->result());

printComments($comments);
```

that'is that simple...

Comment: I did as you answered, but this part `'child' => buildComments($this->commentId)` causes the problem. I changed $this to $item and now It displays only one comment (I did a var_dump for the $result).
Don't you think we need to pass a array into the buildComments() method ? I suppose `$item->commentId` will give me only a single value.
when I tried to change the parameter for the buildComments inside the array for child to $list The page displayed a error "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted...."

Comment: Sorry I wrote the code very late of the night. I fixed the code. Should be like this: `'child' => buildComments($list, $item->commentId)`